# Use pandas to read in text file with row as column names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a project to read in a text file of variable length which will be generated by a user. There are several comments at the beginning of the text file, one of which needs to be used as the column name. I know it is possible to do this with genfromtxt(), but I am required to use pandas. Here is the beginning of a sample text file:

```
#GeneratedFile
#This file will be generated by a user
#a b c d f g h i j k l m n p q r s t v w x y z
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
```

I need #a, b, c,... to be the column names. I tried the following lines of code to read in the data and change it to an array, but it returned only rows and ignored the column names.

```
import pandas as pd    
data = pd.read_table('example.txt',header=2)    
d = pd.DataFrame.as_matrix(data)
```

Is there a way to do this without using genfromtxt()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way may be to try following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('example.txt', sep='\s+', engine='python', header=2)

# the first column name become #a so, replacing the column name
df.rename(columns={'#a':'a'}, inplace=True)

# alternatively, other way is to replace # from all the column names
#df.columns = [column_name.replace('#', '') for column_name in df.columns]
print(df)
```

Result:

```
   a  b  c  d  f  g  h  i  j   k ...   p   q   r   s   t   v   w   x   y   z
0  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8   9 ...  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22
1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 ...  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23

[2 rows x 23 columns]
```